# Return is happening before the loop finishes execution

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am using for loop and return is happening before the loop finishes execution. I cant use .Map method because i have some conditions in between and want to break the loop in between.

```
 const getCompanies = async(searchURL,reqBody) => {
    const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
    businessMap = cheerio('a.business-name', html);
      for(var i=0; i < businessMap.length; i++) {
        linkNew =  baseURL + businessMap[i].attribs.href;
        const innerHtml = await rp(linkNew);
        ..
        ...My Code with conditions here 
        .....
        ......
        ......
        values.push( [a,b,c,d,e,f]);
        
        
      }
     return values

}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve the problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left. If not, please let me know and I'll try to further help you.

Comment: No it didnt helped sorry

Comment: please add the whole code (where it says `My Code with conditions here`) so we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options here:

1. You have a `break` that gets executed where it is says `My code with conditions here`.
2. `rp` doesn't return a `Promise`.

As for the second option, here's a quick code to show you that the final line of an async function gets executed only when all `await`s are finished:

```js
const delay = (ms) => {
   return new Promise(r => {
      setTimeout(r, ms);
      console.log("delayed", ms);
   });
}
const run = async () => {
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       await delay(1000);
   }
   console.log("finished");
}
run();
```